# Inserting three thousand string data in database with FMDB using isTransaction

Tags: ios, swift3, fmdb

I'm trying to insert about 3 thousand string data into my app upon first launch. The problem I'm having is the inserting part is taking too long around 15-20secs. I looked up on ways to make it faster which the isTransaction method comes up, but I have no idea how to use it. I tried many examples online but doesn't seem to fit my situation very well. Help would be very much appreciated.

```
    func insertWordData() {

    if openDatabase() {


        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "messagesToRead", ofType: "json") {
        var query = ""
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)

            let jsonObj = JSON(data: data)
            if jsonObj != JSON.null {
                for (_, jsonObj) in jsonObj {

                    let WordString = jsonObj["FIELD1"]
                    let WordDefinition = jsonObj["FIELD2"]

                    query += "insert into words (\(field_WordID), \(field_WordString), \(field_WordDefinition)) values (null, '\(WordString)', '\(WordDefinition)');"
                }
            }
            if !database.executeStatements(query) {
                print("Failed to insert initial data into the database.")
                print(database.lastError(), database.lastErrorMessage())
            }
            else {
                //print(words)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
        }

        database.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was fixed all i had to do was add database.beginTransaction() before the for loop and database.commit() before database.close(). The speed went from 15-20secs to 0.5sec